# Help understanding machine learning video

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, algorithms, machine-learning

I am currently following a long this video, which is an introduction to Machine Learning.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esTIhqAFKu4&list=PLGd9Gn0_Oc65os52iy4jwvex2q50r5q0U&index=27&t=2818s)

At 47:15 to 48:45 the professor goes on to talk about, how "non normalizing" (sorry, I have a hard time hearing him even with subtitles on its a mess) the dimension of the vector goes down by 1. So having a vector in the realm of R^(p) gives a dimension of R^(p-1). He even uses the example of if a vector was in R^2 than it would be R^1. This seems wrong, but it might be me who have a hard time understanding him. Can someone brighter than me shine some lights on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's "norm normalized".  The lecturer is just saying that if you normalize a nonzero vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ you get an element $x/||x|| \in S^{p-1}$ (I'm not sure why you've written R both times - that's not what is said).  This is purely definitions - nothing is happening here.

Comment: Ahhh, he is saying "norm normalized" I heard it as "non normalized" which totally caught me off guard, now it all makes sense. Thank you so much @Matthew Towers!

Comment: you're welcome, I'll write an answer to get this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lecturer is saying "norm normalized", where "norm" refers to the usual Euclidean length/norm function written $|| \cdot ||$.  If $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$ is nonzero then if we "norm normalize" it the result is $x / ||x||$.  That's got norm 1, so it belongs to the $(p-1)$ sphere $S^{p-1}$ (because this is *defined* to be the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^p$ with norm 1).

For example, if you take a nonzero vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then normalize it you get something on the unit circle $S^1$.